# Matching two string vectors disregarding the order of the element names

Tags: r, regex, string, vector, functional-programming

Below, I want to `match()` two string vectors: my `first` vector and my `second1` vector as in:

```
( desired_output = match(first, second1) ) #> [1] 4 5 1 6 2 3
```

But my `second1` vector could have its two-part string elements in reverse such as instead of `"perf.acog"` being `"acog.perf"` as shown in my `second2` vector.

**Question:** Can we have `match(first, second2)` produce the same output as `match(first, second1)` does?

***NOTE:*** The two-part string elements may be connected by any separator defined within `"[^[:alnum:]]+"` such as `"."` (ex. `"perf.acog"`), `"_"` (ex. `"perf_acog"`) etc. So, a general/functional answer is appreciated.

```
first = c("asom.acog", "conf.acog", "perf.acog", "conf.asom", "perf.asom", 
          "perf.conf")

second1 = c("perf.acog", "perf.asom", "perf.conf", "asom.acog", "conf.acog", 
           "conf.asom")

second2 = c("acog.perf", "asom.perf", "conf.perf", "acog.asom", "acog.conf", 
            "asom.conf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rev` on a string `strsplit` by non-word characters `\\W`.

EDIT: Also included "first" in separator generalization to enable matching if both strings can have any non-character separator.

```
match(sub("\\W", "", first), lapply(strsplit(second2, "\\W"), 
    \(x) paste(rev(x), collapse="")))
[1] 4 5 1 6 2 3
```

Test:

```
identical(
  match(first, second1), 
  match(sub("\\W", "", first), lapply(strsplit(second2, "\\W"), 
    \(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=""))))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @SimonHarmel I focussed on "secondX", see edit if "first" may also contain different separators.